# Paypal REST api invoice scope

Tags: rest, paypal

So I'm trying to [fetch invoices](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/invoicing/v2/#invoices_list) on behalf of a customer who has logged in with [Paypal Oauth2](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/log-in-with-paypal/integrate/).

When I try with curl with a valid token

```bash
curl -v -X GET https://api-m.paypal.com/v2/invoicing/invoices\?total_required\=true \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

I get permission denied

```bash
{"localizedMessage":"No permission for the requested operation. ","suppressed":[],"name":"PERMISSION_DENIED","message":"No permission for the requested operation. ","details":[{"field":null,"value":null,"location":null,"issue":"No permission for the requested operation. ","description":null}],"information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/permissions/","debug_id":"3b3e0813dca9f"}%
```

Which makes sense since I don't have the permission in the response object which contains the token

```json
{
"scope": "https://uri.paypal.com/services/checkout/one-click-with-merchant-issued-token https://uri.paypal.com/services/payments/realtimepayment https://uri.paypal.com/services/payments/payment/authcapture openid profile https://uri.paypal.com/services/payments/refund https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card https://uri.paypal.com/services/reporting/search/read https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/.* https://uri.paypal.com/services/subscriptions https://uri.paypal.com/services/applications/webhooks https://uri.paypal.com/services/paypalattributes email",
"access_token": "MY_ACCESS_TOKEN",
"token_type": "Bearer",
"expires_in": 28800,
"refresh_token": "MY_REFRESH_TOKEN",
"nonce": "2023-09-08T19:49:05abcdefghijklmn",
"state": "some-state"
}
```

Which makes me wonder why since I have tried every combination of the invoice scope when before I begin the Oauth process, here they are:

```js
let SCOPES:string[] = [
    ...
    "https://uri.paypal.com/services/invoicing/invoices/readwrite",
    "https://uri.paypal.com/services/invoicing/invoices/read",
    "https://uri.paypal.com/services/invoicing",
    "https://uri.paypal.com/services/.*",
    "https://uri.paypal.com/v2/invoicing/invoices",
    "https://uri.paypal.com/v2/invoicing/invoices/.*",
    ...
]
```

What am I missing here? Where can I even find all the scopes available that are up to date, everything I have found online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The issue are 2 fold.

1. There was caching in nextjs going which made things hard to debug.
2. Also when re-authorizing, you just get the old permission back, you have to remove the old authorization. I went into the [customer dashboard](https://www.paypal.com/businessprofile/partner/consents) to do it.